# Changes on published Globalization.en.resx not longer recognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

in my web project in Visual Studio (VS) 2013 there are 2 Globalization files for language support: Globalization.resx for German and Globalization.en.resx for English.

The last year while publishing to the Server everythings works fine. For the last 2 days only the changes to the Globalization.en.resx are no longer recognized. It seems, if there would be a hidden old version.

When debugging in VS, everything is displayed in Chrome correctly.

A look through dotPeek to the published Globalization.en.resx in the resources.resources.dll in the bin/en folder shows that all changes have been correctly applied.

I emptied the cache in the browser several times.

Thanks for your help.

Daniel

Comment: Possibly related: [Resource Files and ASP.NET MVC Projects](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. An old version of the Resources.resources.dll was mistakenly copied from bin/en to bin. So deleting the file solve the problem.